# How to calculate list values with the same (key) name

Tags: c#

I have a list with:

```
    public class ListContent
    {
        public string OrderName { get; set; }

        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to add the OrderNumber's if the OrderName is more common in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all with LINQ:

- start with LINQ [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby), grouping on the OrderName
- you now have a list of groups, one per order name, containing all of the ListContent structures with that OrderName. You can then sum these to into a new aggregated ListContent

e.g.

```
var groupedOrders = orders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderName)
                          .Select(g => new ListContent {
                                           OrderName = g.Key,
                                           OrderValue = g.Sum(o => o.OrderValue)
                                       })
                          .ToList();
```

You can probably be a little cleverer too and not construct a new ListContent where there was already only one with that OrderName, but this is the simpler-to-understand version.

Answer (score 0):

If your list contains more than one same `OrderName` then you can take `group`. And then you can take `sum` of all `OrderNumber` that are in same group like

```
var result = (from o in listContents
              group o by o.OrderName into grp
              select new
              {
                  OrderName = grp.Key,
                  Total = grp.Select(x => x.OrderNumber).Sum()
              }).ToList();
```

Where `listContents` is your list of class `ListContent`.

And then you can use the above `result` to print it's item values like

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OrderName: " + item.OrderName);
    Console.WriteLine("Total: " + item.Total);
}
```